# How get an ICodeElement from CsToken

Tags: c#, stylecop

I try to code a custom rule in stylecop for java style curvy brackets like this :

```
public void myfunction(int argument) {
body();
//.......
}
```

My actual code is :

```
    public override void AnalyzeDocument(CodeDocument document) {
                var csharpDocument = (CsDocument)document;

                for (var tokenNode = csharpDocument.Tokens.First; tokenNode != null; tokenNode = tokenNode.Next) {

               if (tokenNode.Value.CsTokenType == CsTokenType.OpenCurlyBracket) {
                        if (tokenNode.Value.LineNumber == tokenNode.Previous.Value.LineNumber
                            || tokenNode.Value.LineNumber == tokenNode.Next.Value.LineNumber) {
                            this.AddViolation(tokenNode.Value,
                                              tokenNode.Value.LineNumber,
                                                "OpenCurlyBracketBadLocation");
                        }
                    }

               if (tokenNode.Value.CsTokenType == CsTokenType.CloseCurlyBracket) {
                        if (tokenNode.Value.LineNumber != tokenNode.Previous.Value.LineNumber
                            || tokenNode.Value.LineNumber == tokenNode.Next.Value.LineNumber) {
                            this.AddViolation(tokenNode.Value,
                                              tokenNode.Value.LineNumber,
                                                "CloseCurlyBracketBadLocation");
                        }
                    }

                }
```

But this line :

```
this.AddViolation(tokenNode.Value,
                  tokenNode.Value.LineNumber,
                  "CloseCurlyBracketBadLocation");
```

Doesn't compile because function arguments type don't match.
First argument need an ICodeElement and I have a CsToken...
But in SDK this way it used... So anyone know a solution ? Or maybe a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the first argument is an `ICodeElement` is that the target of a violation must be something against which a `SuppressMessageAttribute` may be applied.  You could climb the token's `Parent` chain until you find an `ICodeElement`, but that wouldn't be particularly efficient.  An approach that would be better aligned with the intended usage of the SDK would be to use the `WalkDocument` method to visit elements (as is done in the built-in [`StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules` analyzer](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Project/Src/AddIns/CSharp/Analyzers/LayoutRules.cs) that implements StyleCop's own curly brace verification rules).